# Slow Query Log Only Logs Few Queries

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, performance-tuning, mariadb-10.1

Slow query is enabled but only logs few queries when you retrieve the slow log.  It’s been working ok all last week, suddenly this week, it only logs just 2 or 3 queries.
Long query time = 0.01 and I expect to see anything above 1sec but this is not the case.

I had to query performance schema table to view long running queries instead of the slow log.

What could have changed?

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer what's changed on your systems. Did someone improve the queries? Add indexes? Change tuning? Or ANALYZE TABLES?  Maybe run some of the last week slow queries and see if they are still slow. Does the performance schema show queries for the last week?

Comment: Please provide all the slowlog settings you have.  (There are about a dozen for 10.1.)  Are the missing queries "admin"?  Replicated?  Show us some samples.